# meteor - does having publication rules in lib folder present a security risk?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am following a meteor tutorial on [eventedmind](https://www.eventedmind.com/classes/build-a-multi-page-app-with-iron-meteor-6737880d/using-reactive-state-928d23fb). We put the todos collection information in `lib/collections/todos.js`. The app was generated with iron.

When I load the app in the browser I can plainly see the folder under sources. It looks like:

```
Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');

// if server define security rules
// server code and code inside methods are not affected by allow and deny
// these rules only apply when insert, update, and remove are called from untrusted client code

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // first argument is id of logged in user. (null if not logged in)
  Todos.allow({
    // can do anythin if you own the document
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
      return userId === doc.userId;
    },

    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
      return userId === doc.userId;
    },

    remove: function (userId, doc) {
      return userId === doc.userId;
    }
  });

  // The deny method lets you selectively override your allow rules
  // every deny callback must return false for the database change to happen
  Todos.deny({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
      return false;
    },

    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
      return false;
    },

    remove: function (userId, doc) {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

My question is does this propose a security threat? If a javascript file is stored in the `lib` directory can it be hijacked by the client?

Answer (score 0):

Never ever ever ever use `Meteor.isServer`. Instead put your server methods under `/server`. Code there is *not* served up to the client.

I disagree with redress that moving inserts to the server is more secure than doing inserts on the client. After all, a logged-in user can simply open the console and type `Meteor.call('addPost', new_post_fields)` (after having inspected a document in `postsCollection` to reverse engineer the schema) and the server will happily execute that. The cost of doing the insert via a method call is that you lose latency compensation, one of the major benefits of Meteor. Your application will feel laggy because your inserts all require a server round-trip to reflect in the UI.

Let me be more specific in response to redress' comments:

1. If your method code is in /lib it will be visible to both the client and the server and will run once in each place, with latency compensation. It can be modified on the client but not on the server. But it can be seen.
2. If your method code is in /server it will only be visible to the server and will run *without* latency compensation.
3. Meteor.call() can be invoked from the console in the client with any arguments. Your method code needs to protect against such attacks.

I recommend using a combination of allow/deny rules on the server along with [aldeed:simple-schema](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/simple-schema) at a minimum to control what goes into your collections.

Comment: server methods are the exact reason latency compensation comes into play: a server method is invoked and the UI is updated immediately (as if from the client).  latency compensation doesnt mean anything if everything happens on the client...this article explains exactly what I just did
https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-latency-compensation

Comment: also, you did not answer OP's question.  please remove or update your answer...all security checks should happen on the server.  that is an indisputable fact of DDP.

Comment: The article you cite requires the method code be in /lib, i.e. on both the client and the server, in order to get latency compensation. This makes your server code *visible* to the client. Even though it can't be changed, it can be seen which can help one figure out how to attack it. Agree that all security checks should be on the server but want to add that it's *better* if these remain opaque to the client. IMO your solution is an anti-pattern.